# A String Describing the Additions, Removals and Changes Between Strings?

Tags: javascript, string, version-control, storage, string-comparison

I've been attempting to create a version control system using strings (Files in Base64) in Javascript. I figure instead of storing every version of a file as a completely new file this will cut down on space. Instead I would like to create a chain of differences based on an original file.

For example:
`new_version("Hello world! My name is Bob.", "Hello world! My Papa is Sam.")` should return something like `?16?P?1?pa?4?Sam?1?` Where the integer represents how many spaces to skip before making a change. The issue I'm facing is words with different lengths. Replacing Sam with Bill would completely alter the remaining string. I'm wondering if there is a better way than comparing every character as I've done for my prototype.

Comment: Think in bits rather than btyes - or use GitLab :-)